# Google document cloud sync on macOS

Tags: google-drive, google-sync

I recently upgraded my computer and such Apps as were compatible with an M2 all moved across without any issues. MacBook Air M2 Sonoma 14.3 (23D56)

In a bit of housekeeping I removed my access to some Google Drive folders that had been shared with me more than 5 years ago.

Since then,

```
 Google Drive
Version: 86.0.2.0 (Apple Silicon)
```

throws me two errors at some point every time I use the computer. These are access issues thrown up by two of the folders to which I removed access. In other words, "you no longer have access to these files so I can't Sync them".

The program itself says "Your files are up to date" and in Notifications

```
> "No new notifications Notifications will show up here"
> 
> "Everything is up to date"
```

and further, in error list

```
>     "Looks good
>     Errors related to backing up or syncing your files will show up here"
```

I have no idea where those problematic folders are, they are not on my laptop ( I did a root search with various search keys) and they are not on either of my Google Drives. I can't recall who shared them with me.)

Whist this is an irritation rather than a problem, I have no idea how to proceed.

I have tried removing and reinstalling the program.

```
**I have looked very hard for a duplicate problem and I can't see one. Google forums directed me here**
```

Any idea about How I can proceed with diagnosis?